# Trying to embed Java applet into Google site

Tags: java, svn, applet, embed

I am currently learning how to embed Java Applets into my Google Site.
So far, I have uploaded my java applet to the svn on my personal site:
http://comp-212-unic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/

Then, I go to my google site and include an Embed Gadget. In the widget I paste the following code:

```
<applet name="FollowMe" code="FollowMe.class" archive="FollowMe.jar"
codebase="http://comp-212-unic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/applet/"
width = 300 height = 300>
<param name=dialColor value="FFFEeFEFE">
<param name=hairLineColor value="FF42C151">
<param name=hoursNeedleColor value="7F000000">
<param name=minutesNeedleColor value="7F0000FF">
<param name=secondsNeedleColor value="7FFF0000">
Sorry, the CircleClock Applet could not be started. Please make sure that Java 1.4.2 (or later) is installed and active in your browser (<a href="http://java.sun.com/getjava">Click here to install Java now</a>)
```

When I visit the site and click on the applet, it gives me the following error: "ClassNotFoundException". I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, as this is my first time attempting this, I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: http://comp-212-unic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/applet/FollowMe.jar -> **Not Found**

The requested URL /svn/trunk/applet/FollowMe.jar was not found on this server.